# Fourier transform Carr-Madan method on an arbitrar initial $S_0$ values

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, european-options, fourier-transform

As mentioned in Carr-Madan's paper, [here](https://engineering.nyu.edu/sites/default/files/2018-08/CarrMadan2_0.pdf), the European call option is:
$$
C_T(k)=\frac{e^{\alpha k}}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\mathcal{Re}\left(e^{-iuk}\psi(u)\right)du
$$
where
$$
\psi(u)=e^{-rT}\frac{\phi_T(u-(\alpha+1)i)}{\alpha^2 + \alpha - u^2 + i(2\alpha+1)u}
$$
and $\phi_T(u)$ is the characteristic function for a given process.
Please refer to the paper all parameters.

So my question is, this derivation is based on the factor $S_0=1$ and define $k=\ln(K)$.

I am trying to derive the formula for any $S_0$ starting with $k=\ln(K/S_0)$ and $x=\ln(S_T/S_0)$, then end up with something like:
$$
\psi(u)=e^{-rT}S_0\frac{\phi_T(u-(\alpha+1)i)}{\alpha^2 + \alpha - u^2 + i(2\alpha+1)u}
$$
Intuitively, it looks OK to me. But is there any other sources with a general $S_0$?
Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I may be wrong but I remember that formula to allow for a general $S_0$? If I remember correctly, Carr and Madan only assume $S_0=1$ for the second (time value) approach? I once wrote down a general formula for the second case. But the first ``standard'' approach from Carr and Madan incorporates a general $S_0$ via the characteristic function of $S_T$, i.e. $\phi_T(u)$? I may be wrong though and will look at the paper again.

Comment: Thank you @KeSchn, I think you may be correct that Carr and Madan incorporate a general $S_0$ via the characteristic function of $S_T$. I'll take a look at details as well, but feel free to answer this question.

Comment: Given that you can incorporate a general $S_0$ via $\phi_T(u)$, why would you still need the Fourier transform of the call option with respect to $\ln\left(\frac{K}{S_0}\right)$? Can't you simply take their formula and plug in your general $S_0$?

Comment: I think I need to make sure the meaning of $k=\ln(K/S_0)$ is correct before I can plug into the formula? Here is the part I felt confused...

Comment: Just take the formulae from the paper, use $\phi_T(u)$ according to your model which includes $S_0$ and set $k=\ln(K)$. If you follow the formulae from the paper, you’ll get correct option prices